How to get the sum in array of objects in Laravel 10?
I have this Array of objects where I wanna sum up the quantity having the same 'barcode' field and if it has a different 'location' field it should be separated.
here is my sample object
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "barcode": "555",
    "description": "pencil",
    "quantity": "3",
    "location": "drawer1",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "barcode": "555",
    "description": "pencil",
    "quantity": "1",
    "location": "drawer1",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "barcode": "123",
    "description": "paper",
    "quantity": "1",
    "location": "drawer2",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "barcode": "123",
    "description": "paper",
    "quantity": "8",
    "location": "drawer2",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "barcode": "123",
    "description": "paper",
    "quantity": "8",
    "location": "drawer1",
  },

]

and here is my desired result.
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "barcode": "555",
    "description": "pencil",
    "quantity": "4",
    "location": "drawer1",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "barcode": "123",
    "description": "paper",
    "quantity": "9",
    "location": "drawer2",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "barcode": "123",
    "description": "paper",
    "quantity": "8",
    "location": "drawer1",
  },

]

just for additional information, I got this code from my previous question but now I am clueless on how to integrate this location field.
$collection
    ->groupBy('barcode')
    ->map(fn ($group, $key) => [
        'id' => $group->first()['id'],
        'barcode' => $group->first()['barcode'],
        'description' => $group->first()['description'],
        'qty' => $group->sum('qty'),
    ])
    ->values();

Thanks, and hopefully someone will be able to point out what am missing here.

Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/78611417/20415955 ?

@Edson , I have posted my answer. Please check and let me know.

If you follow this map loop, you should receive the expected results.
$data = collect(json_decode($jsonInput, true));
              
    $grouped = $data->groupBy(function ($item) {
        return $item['barcode'] . '_' . $item['location'];
    })->map(function ($group) {
        return [
            'id' => $group->first()['id'],
            'barcode' => $group->first()['barcode'],
            'description' => $group->first()['description'],
            'quantity' => $group->sum('quantity'),
            'location' => $group->first()['location'],
        ];
    })->values()->each(function ($item, $index) {
        $item['id'] = $index + 1;
    });
    
    $jsonOutput = $grouped->toJson();


Do this.I think it will work.
$collection
    ->groupBy(['barcode','location'])
    ->map(fn ($group, $key) => [
        'id' => $group->first()['id'],
        'barcode' => $group->first()['barcode'],
        'description' => $group->first()['description'],
        'qty' => $group->sum('quantity'),
        'location' => $group->first()['location'],
    ])
    ->values();

For more information about how collections work you can check this link where you will get a clear idea about how to work with collections
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/collections#extending-collections

thanks for your feedback,  I tried your code but am getting an error 'Undefined array key "id"'

@Edson,there might be some objects in the array that doesn't have id.If id is absent then remove the 'id'=>.. part from query,it will work.Please check that as well and let me know.

ID has always have value. It still doesn't work if I comment on the ID next error will be  'Undefined array key "barcode"' and when I comment on that next error will show. thanks

@Edson,is it id or ID?

sorry its 'id' small caps
